# Why $\int_t^T \int_0^s f(s,u)dW(u)ds=\int_0^t \int_t^T f(s,u)dsdW(u)+\int_t^T \int_u^Tf(s,u)dsdW(u)$??

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Maybe it's trivial but why can we write this integral as the sum of these two integrals? We use Fubini Theorem but I don't understand why there are such limits on the right hand side.

Comment: What do you mean by $dW(u)$? $dW(u)= W'(u)\, du$?

Comment: It's stochastic integral with respect to Wiener Process $W$ (Brownian Motion).

Comment: Your formula follows directly from the stochastic Fubini theorem (reference can surely be googled). The area of integration consists of the square $[t,T]\times[t,T]$ plus a triangle hence the two terms on the right hand side.

Comment: Small correction: the area of integration is the rectangle $[0,t]\times[t,T]$ plus a triangle.